# AutoAction not working with Locator and LocatorPane

Tags: plotting, dynamic, locator

This code is from the "Neat Examples" part on the `LocatorPane` page of the documentation:

```
LocatorPane[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}], Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}], 
 Appearance -> Table[Style["●", Hue[h/50]], {h, 50}], 
 AutoAction -> True]
```

When my mouse enters the output, the nearest locator jumps to the position of the mouse, but does not follow it afterwards. Clicking is required to move the locator. I cannot move any other locators until I click somewhere outside the output. If I double click the output, the locator follows my mouse for a single pixel. Using `Locator` produces similar results.

Comment: Works fine in _v9.0.1_. Which version are you in?

Comment: I am using version 12.1.

Comment: I suggest reporting it to WRI.